# Else without if vba

Tags: vba, if-statement, variables, combobox

I'm beginner. Could you tell me why I have this error : "Else without IF"?

```
If ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""
Else: FROM = ""
End If
```

Comment: `If ComboBox3.Value = "" Then FROM = ""` is the single line syntax of `If`. You cannot mix signle line syntax et multiline syntax. You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements)

Comment: In the VBA Ide you can put the cursor on a Keyword and then press F1 to bring up the MS help page for the Keyword.  Its helpful if you do this and make sure you understand the text before posting on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Else: FROM = ""
'Notice the colon after the `Else`
```

Edit: The error at the first `ElseIf` is caused by the implicitely closed `If`. You would have to go to a new line after `Then` or the `If` will be closed implicitely.

```
'Fixed Code:
If ComboBox3.Value = "" Then
    FROM = ""
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" Then
    FROM = ""
'Your code continue...
End If
```

Comment: I corrected it. I have error in first ElseIf.

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Please see updated post.

Comment: You have never update your post (question). Also, is there any problem in my answer? I've tested it out and it works like a charm.